# Optimization: Find minimizer along linestring

Tags: optimization, computational-geometry

Given some function `f(x)` and a set of points `A` representing a linestring (or polygonal chain), I am searching for the point on this linestring that minimizes `f(x)`.

An iterative approach would be to do gradient descent and use the linestring direction for linesearch. However, I want to find a non-iterative solution. How do I formulate and solve an optimization problem that minimizes `f(x)` and constrains `x` to the linestring? Can someone point me to any resources about either some theory or an application?

The figure shows an example. `f(x)` is represented by the contour plot and the linestring is black.
[image: Example image]

Comment: Your function restricted to the line segments is one-dimensional. Thus this is equivalent to finding the minima on several 1-D bounded problems, and then picking the smallest. However note that even in 1-D you do not have a bulletproof way of finding a global optimum of arbitrary function, so you would likely have to rely on some iterative method. If you know something specific for these 1-D functions then it may be simpler (e.g. you know the global minimum of a quadratic function).

Comment: if it's 1D case, you may wish to find the values of $f$ where it's derivative is 0, solve $f'(p)=0$ for $p$. Then compare these with boundary values given your segment is $[a,b]$. $f(p)?f(a)?f(b)$. this is non-iterative. (note: there might be more than one $p$)

Comment: If we can assume that there is a single minimum of f(x) along the piecewise-linear path, one could probably use a contour plot routine like the one used to produce the plot here. Many contour plotting routines allow exporting the contour lines in numerical form, and then it would be a matter of finding the contour line corresponding to a smallest value that intersects the path of interest. This method would be sufficient if high accuracy is not needed; or at least it would give a good starting point for refining the solution by an iterative method.

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates of a polychain can be used to easily form a continuous piecewise function $p: [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ that can produce any coordinate within the curve represented by the polychain. Thus, given you know your original function $f(x)$, the new function to optimize is $g(\alpha) := f(p(\alpha))$ where we restrict $\alpha \in [0, 1]$.

As this is now a continuous 1-D problem, this simplifies solution procedure quite a bit, though this could still be challenging if your function is extremely non-convex even after restricting it to this 1 dimensional view. If it is non-convex but not *too* non-convex (ie not many local optima) and you do not need real-time performance, you could always do some brute force thing like compute a set $A$ of $m$ values from $[0,1]$, evaluate $g(\alpha)$ for each $\alpha \in A$, and then use $\alpha^* = \arg \min_{\alpha \in A} g(\alpha)$ as the starting point for some 1-D optimization scheme of your choosing.